# How to implement toolBar in tabBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitoolbar

I would like to implement a toolbar in my tab bar or ender my tab bar like in the photo app. I show you :

[Tab Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64NWv.png)
turn to when select button tapped
[Tool bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2orC.png)

I already try to put the toolbar in the Tab bar controller view, without success.

Thanks for your replies !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this might be the sort of behaviour you're looking for. You don't have to use a custom `UIButton` you could use a `UIBarButtonItem`, but that's up to you, I just chose to demonstrate it with a custom `UIButton` to show you that this is one way of doing it.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var selectButton: UIButton!
    var isInSelectMode = false
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        selectButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        selectButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        selectButton.setTitle("Select", for: .normal)
        view.addSubview(selectButton)
        
        let trashButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .trash, target: nil, action: nil)
        toolbarItems = [trashButton]
        
        selectButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            selectButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -15),
            selectButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor, constant: 15),
        ])
        
    }
    
    @objc func selectButtonTapped() {
        isInSelectMode = !isInSelectMode
        if isInSelectMode {
            selectButton.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
            tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
            tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
            navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)
            
        } else {
            selectButton.setTitle("Select", for: .normal)
            tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
            tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundColor = .clear
            navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)
            
        }
        
    }

}
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image: demo gif of what the code does]

Comment: Thanks for you example, I found how to do with it. I use a toolbar without navigationController, I put it ender the tab bar and I change the layout to Autoresizing Mask.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution for this is to hide the tabBar on some event (Photos app has a button which does this). Then create a custom ToolBar and add it as a subview of the view controller.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I explain how I make it ender the example of Demented07

Answer (score 0):

==> Tested in `iOS` 15.5

==> First your view controller must embed in `UINavigationController`

==> in `viewDidLoad` set `editButtonItem` to `navigationItem` and also configure `UINavigationController` native `toolbarItems`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
    self.toolbarItems = [UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .trash, target: self, action: nil)]
}
```

==> After that `override` `setEditing` Method and implement your logic as required. and you are done

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    self.tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: true)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = editing
    self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(!editing, animated: true)
}
```

[You can check it out image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiWHT.gif)

==> But there is one issue and need further assistance... if anyone have any idea then comment bellow..

> Issue : `toolbar` leave `safeArea` space and came top of that...

You can also checkout Demo [Native toolbar Demo](https://gitlab.com/santespatel/native-toolbar-with-tabbar)